# Google map show different distance between two dastination

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I am creating a window form application, which calculate the distance between two locations by their Lat-Long using google API. This works fine, But i notice that some time api give different result (distance) for same locations.

**Example :-**

**Location-A** =>  **Mumbai** (19.075983 , 72.877655)

**Location-B** =>  **Delhi** (28.704060 , 77.102493)

When i calculate the distance from **location-A** To **location-B**

```
decimal Distance = EmployeeTaskWorkLogManager.getDistance(string.Concat(19.075983, ", ", 72.877655), string.Concat(28.704060, ", ", 77.102493));
```

This shows
Distance = **1423.297**

And when i calculate the distance from **location-B** To **location-A**

```
decimal Distance = EmployeeTaskWorkLogManager.getDistance(string.Concat(28.704060, ", ", 77.102493), string.Concat(19.075983, ", ", 72.877655));
```

This shows
Distance = **1415.239**

This the code that i am using to calculate distance between two locations,

```
 public static decimal getDistance(string origin, string destination)
        {
            decimal num;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            decimal num1 = new decimal(0);
            string[] strArrays = new string[] { "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=", origin, "&destinations=", destination, "&key=****" };
            string str = string.Concat(strArrays);
            JObject jObjects = JObject.Parse(EmployeeTaskWorkLogManager.fileGetContents(str));
            try
            {
                num1 = (decimal)jObjects.SelectToken("rows[0].elements[0].distance.value");
                num = num1 / new decimal(1000);
            }
            catch
            {
                num = num1;
            }
            return num;
        }
```

I Checked each line of my code, but unable to find why this difference has occurs.

Comment: Do you check this distance on google maps

Comment: Yes now i have checked on google maps and i shocked google maps also shows the difference. Does anybody know why google maps show this difference ?

Comment: You should not post your private Google API key in your code online ...

Comment: Even i have noticed the google maps shows different distance as compared to react native geolib library that takes lat/lng for two locations. Any resolutions anyone?

Answer (score 3):

The Google Maps Distance Matrix API does not calculate a straight-line or big-circle distance between two points. Instead it returns the distance according to the mode of travel (which you haven't specified in your API call, so it defaults to `driving`).
Think about it: there is no way that you will travel the *exact* distance in both directions, and the difference will become more marked the longer the journey and the more route changes it requires. It will depend on freeway off ramps (not available at particular intersections in both directions), one way streets, etc etc.

Therefore, the result is as expected.

Source: [Google Maps Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)